# Why does the result of accessing this object property's value give separate letters? and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const game = {
  team1: "Bayern Munich",
  team2: "Borrussia Dortmund",
  odds: {
    team1: 1.33,
    team2: 6.5,
  },
};

for (const [team, odd] of Object.entries(game.odds)) {
  console.log(`Odd of victory ${Object.values(game[team])}: ${odd}`);
}
```

The result in the console is as follows.....

```
Odd of victory B,a,y,e,r,n, ,M,u,n,i,c,h: 1.33
Odd of victory B,o,r,r,u,s,s,i,a, ,D,o,r,t,m,u,n,d: 6.5
```

what is the wrong with that code and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove `Object.values` from inside the loop

```js
for (const [team, odd] of Object.entries(game.odds)) {
    console.log(`Odd of victory ${game[team]}: ${odd}`);
}
```